# What is the formula and log base for idf?

Tags: tfidf, search-engine

To calculate tf-idf, we do:

tf*idf

tf=number of times word occurs in document

What is formula for idf and log base:

1. Log(number of documents/number of documents containing the word)
2. Log((1+number of documents)/(1+number of documents containing the word))
3. 1+Log(number of documents/number of documents containing the word)
4. 1+Log((1+number of documents)/(1+number of documents containing the word))

Answer (score 1):

There a a number of variation how to calculate inverse document frequency. Have a look at the wiki page ([Tf-Idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)) or scikit-learn's [`TfidfVetorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#tfidf-term-weighting) class.